# Cannot Load PictureBox Images from URLs

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and i am making a Tic-Tac-Toe game in Visual Studio 2010. I've already made the whole structural part of it, but i am having trouble loading images from pictureBoxes. The command i am using is pictureBox.Load(string imageUrl), and it works fine when i use it on the method TicForm_Load, since TicForm is a Form:

```
private void TicForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //picture1 is the name of a pictureBox created on TicForm.cs (Design)
            picture1.Load(imageUrl);
        }
```

However, in my game, the changes to the images in the pictureBoxes are controlled by a class called Board. I want to be able to change images from this class.

I've already set the modifiers of the pictureBoxes to public, yet, if i want to access a command from TicForm, the program asks me to instantiate an object of the type TicForm first:

```
//Somewhere on the class Board
TicForm ticform = new Ticform();
ticform.picLocation00.Load(imageUrl);
```

This, however, causes an exception StackOverflow, since i create a new Board, at the start of the TicForm class, and i create a new TicForm, at the start of the Board class.

I would really appreciate an answer from someone with more experience / knowledge in Visual Studio than me. How do you normally change the images from the pictureBox in run-time? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are new to C# you shouldn't use Visual Studio 2010, you can get Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition for free from http://www.visualstudio.com

Comment: Instead of trying to fiddle with the control directly, you could create a public method to receive instruction indicating which image to show in which control

Comment: Not sure which is the parent class, but you should only create the other class in one of the classes.  i.e. `TicForm tf = new TicForm();` inside of the constructor of the `TicForm` class you can create your `TicBoard` class and pass it a reference to the `TicForm` class. Like `TicBoard tb = new TicBoard(this);`

Comment: The Board class shouldn't change the picture directly. It should only provide what picture to be displayed. Then ticform would ask Board class. Lookup for MVVM pattern

Comment: Oh yes... I think i got it. Will try to implement that.

Comment: You have  no problem with Visual Studio - your problem is with PictureBox and code and behavior at runtime. Please [edit] your question to make that  clear, as your title is currently meaningless. The problem is not Visual Studio, and *Problems with* is not an informative or useful subject. Your title should describe the actual problem or question in a way that will have meaning to a future user when it ends up in the results of a search here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will do that in my future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been solved. Instead of using a method from TicForm into a class (which would never work), i created new variables on the class that indicate in what circustamces the method is to be used, and this happens inside the TicForm class.